# Cannot deploy new version to App Engine Flexible

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I tried to deploy new version to app engine. But it keeps saying
`vm_check_disk_space.sh` and `health check` logs.

and on web browser it gives me 502 error saying

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your 
request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

[image]
I have tried 4 times trying to deploy but never worked.
I think you can reproduce this by deploying any project to app engine.

I am using **Google Cloud SDK 157.0.0**
and 
tried to deploy service with java and nodejs environment

Comment: Hi the log entries you are showing are only summary lines from periodic tasks.  Not much info can be extracted from them.   Can you post your app.yaml?  Also can you post the stderr or stdout logs from your app?  It's likely that your app is not coming up healthy.  stderr & stdout would be the logs from your app itself.

Answer (score 0):

I received many weird errors like this while deploying months ago with both maven and gradle.  Various strange things with app.yaml can cause this as well.  Even the example projects provided from google contained strange bugs like this when deployed.

Try one of the test projects that google provides: [Google NodeJS bookshelf app](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/tutorial-app)

(Hopefully this project has been fixed by now and will deploy correctly!!)

Also, it's possible that an old version can prevent your new code from deploying.  Go to your console, and delete/stop all running versions of the service.  (I have had issues with old versions becoming stuck, which causes issues with the new deployment becoming the default service).